# Call function of child view instance from parent view controller

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have a motherView controlled by motherViewController with a container view in it. The container view is controlled by an childViewController. The childView holds an tableView.

Now I have a cleanTableView function in the childViewController, which "resets" the tableView when called.

```
func clean() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
}
```

In my motherView there is a button. When this button is touched it calls an action on motherViewController.

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

       //call clean method of containerView instance

}
```

How do I call, from this action, the cleanTableView function on the specific childView Instance?

Comment: You can set NSNotificationCenter Observer or also Declare Protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only one child view controller:

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    (children.first as? ChildViewController)?.clean()
}
```

**Some additional information regarding an API change / renaming:**

*The `childViewControllers` property has been renamed to `children` in Swift 4.2. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621452-children?changes=latest_minor*

[image: renaming1]
[image: renaming2]

Comment: `children` is Swift 4.2? That sounds like a change to the Foundation classes rather than a change to the language. Can you explain?

Comment: Is that change in iOS 12 then?

Comment: @DuncanC Seems to be a Swift 4.2 specific change indeed (check attached screenshots).

Comment: It sounds like a Foundation change to the Swift names of various functions and properties. There were a fair number of these changes in the Swift 2 -> Swift 3 transition as well.

Comment: Worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, depending on the interconnectivity of the components, and how tightly you want to bind them. Three examples:

- Tight binding: The "mother" VC calls a method on the "child" VC, which calls a method on the child View.
- Loose binding with delegates: Create a delegate protocol, link the child View with the mother VC via this delegate. The mother VC then calls the delegate.
- Disconnected with notifications: Have the child View listen for a specific "clear" notification. Have the Mother VC post that notification. No direct links between the two.

Pros and cons with each method. The best interaction just depends on your specifics.